# How can I use a variable like this?

Tags: actionscript-3, variables

I want to do something like this with a variable in actionscript 3, you can ignore the randomNumber function. It's just to make my question more clear about what I'm doing:

```
function randomNumber(low:Number=0, high:Number=1):Number {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (1+high-low)) + low;
}

randomNumber(1, 3)

var selection:int = randomNumber;

mymovieclip.insideclip(selection);
```

So I want to basically use the contents of the variable to choose a certain movieclip. You can imagine there are multiple insideclip's. So something like insideclip1, insideclip2, insideclip3. I randomly choose a number and put it in a variable called selection, then I want to use mymovieclip.insideclip1, 2 or 3 depending on what number that variable stores.

I'm sure there's a way to do this someone can direct me to figuring out.

Comment: Just to clarify for anyone else who may stumble onto this looking for something similar. I made an array: movieclipArray:Array = [movieclip.insideclip1, movieclip.insideclip2, etc]; and then with the random function I posted above, did something like: var selection = randomNumber(0, 3); and finally could get the result I wanted by: movieclipArray[selection]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many many ways to do this (also based on what you want). One way, you could just store all the "insideclips" in to an array then choose a random index.

Comment: Ah thanks for the suggestion, I'm still a novice so I don't have experience with using arrays but I'll get it! Just out of curiosity, I'm sure using an array will work but I'd also like to know of the other ways to accomplish generally the same goals. And I'll post again if I get the array to work of course.

Comment: In this case, the array is both a method to store the clips and used to make a 'mapping' or index of each movieclip to a number. You could make this mapping another way, for example mark down '1' as clip 1, '2' as clip '2' then use a long if/else if or switch statement if you want to avoid arrays, but I can't say I recommend it as it would result in a lot of duplicate code and harder maintenance depending on how many clips you have.

Comment: Ah yeah I've got it figured out now, thanks for the help mitim. I put the "insideclips" into an array and could easily randomize the selection of which one to use and get it to do what I wanted. Haha and yes I was thinking about the other way you mentioned and almost considered trying the long way before asking here. Glad I decided to approach it differently.

Answer (score 0):

```
var selection:int = randomNumber(1, 3);//randomNumber(1, mymovieclip.numChildren)
var myMovie = mymovieclip.getChildByName("insideclip" + selection);
```

or If you want to get rid of names, you can access it by their depth.

```
var selection:int = randomNumber(1, mymovieclip.numChildren);
var myMovie = mymovieclip.getChildByDepth(selection);
```

Comment: Ah thanks for the answer Moorthy, interesting approach to it. I ended up going with making an array to hold the clips but thank you for the suggestion.